# How is int implemented in any compiler?

Tags: int, compiler-construction

In a 64-bit processor 64 bits of data are processed at a time. So when any arithmetic operation is to be performed it is done in **ALU** using **ACCUMULATOR** which is also 64-bit.

But the size of `int` in most of the case is more than 2 bytes.
How are the 2-byte int implemented (**arithmetic operations**)?

Comment: in most 64-bit processors a 64-bit value is also more than 2 bytes, so int can fit in it without problem

Comment: the ALU **doesn't have ACCUMULATOR** as you said. At the simplest form it just receives 2 operands, an operation selection and output a single operand. In many embedded systems there may be an accumulator register but it's not inside the ALU, and none of the more powerful architectures have it, although there's a little bit remnant in the x86 with the ax/eax/rax

Answer (score -1):

The basic idea is, of course, as binary numbers. But there are many details that complicate things. It depends on the hardware and compiler.

I have used compilers that represented integers in each of the ways I mention here.

One possible way to represent things is just to make the biggest binary integer you can. With 64 bits, and taking one bit back for the sign, you get 2 to the power of 64 minus 1, or a little over 1.8 x 10^19.

If you want to do add and subtract this is OK. But multiplies are tedious because you need to do one multiply for each bit. Floating co-processors can help you there.

Some hardware will support interesting features so taking advantage of it is useful. For example, some CPU chips will support binary-coded-decimal.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal

If you are old enough to remember the Z80, it's the first CPU I ever used that had BCD.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80

This means that you only need to do binary stuff at the 4 bits level, since each digit of your decimal number is set apart from the other digits. If the hardware supports it directly then you can avoid writing code to convert all 64 bits between integer and decimal. It's not as efficient. With 64 bits, and dropping one for the sign, you get only 15 digits.

Again, add and subtract are easy. Multiplying becomes a question of implementing the digit-by-digit multiply in binary, then including the carry for results more than 10.

Different hardware will support things differently. There is the question of big-endian vs little-endian.

https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_3.html

There are lots of other possibilities on esoteric hardware.

Comment: who told you that `multiplies are tedious because you need to do one multiply for each bit`? the low part of the multiplication is always the same, so just do sign or zero extension and do like normal

Comment: @phuclv  You just described "do one multiply for each bit."

Comment: No. I don't even understand what you mean. Regardless of how many bits you multiply, you always have to add them together to get the result. But no modern architectures do mathematics on bits. The narrowest known architecture is 4 bits. To do a 32x32 multiplication on a 16-bit architecture, just multiple 4 16-bit parts and add the result. Only 4 operations are needed, not 32*32 = 1024 bit operations. To do the same on a 64-bit PC, a full 64x64 multiplication can be used, with the 32-bit operands on the low part of the 64-bit register

Comment: @phuclv  To add    b1 b2 b3 b4 and d1 d2 d3 d4, you do 4 bitwise adds, with carry.

Comment: no. The compilers **doesn't do that**. Did you even read the tag of the question? No one is stupid enough to do bit-by-bit addition on a CPU that operates on words when a single instruction works, except for homework exercises. And the FPU isn't relevant here, because it does floating-point operations, not integer operations

Comment: @phuclv But the computer does. The question asks about implementation.

Comment: no, the compiler doesn't do like that. Did you even [see the compiler output](https://godbolt.org/z/DGFxxZ)? It adds all the bits in a register at once, not adding those bits separately

Comment: Sigh.  "But the computer does." "no, the compiler doesn't"  Computer, compiler, let's call the whole thing off.

Comment: the compiler and the CPU do different things. The compiler need to emit instructions to utilize what are available on the CPU